# Is this circuit correct and will work?

Tags: pcb, gps, prototyping

I found this circuit as a gps module on the internet . i look to datasheets and it looks ok. I want to make it for test. is this correct and will work ?

[image]

Credit:
https://www.electroschematics.com/neo-6m-gps-module/

Comment: If that's not your drawing or design then you need to credit it. (This is [site policy](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).) Hit the [edit] link ...

Comment: I add it . Thank you

Comment: a "reserved" pin connected to something looks suspicious.

Comment: Add details of controlled Z to schematic for traces and areas needing ground plane with Vcc ripple specs.